# PHP Array output from result array values

Tags: php, arrays, function

Below is my result array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => test
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => Balikavadhu
    )
)
```

From above array, I want to generate a new array as below:

```
array(3,4) // where 3 and 4 are id values of respective array
```

Any help or quick answer will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another option:

```
 $newArray = [];

 foreach ($arrayResults as $result) {
  $newArray[] = $result['id'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your output array into an array called $arr. Then do this :

```
$newArr = array();
$id = 0;
foreach ($arr as $val)
{
   $newArr[$i] = $val['id'];
   $id++;
}
```

Comment: can we do same with array_push function?

Comment: Can be done. This is one way of doing logically. Yours is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
$newArray = [];

foreach ($arrayResults as $result) {
  array_push($newArray, $result['id']);
}
```